# jQueryMobile, PhoneGap getJSON method not executing

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm running a sample jQueryMobile app that runs in PhoneGap. The problem is that it doesn't run the getJSON callback to retrieve data, shown below:

```
$( function() 

    {       
        $('#searchButton').click(function() 
        {

            alert("search clicked"); <== this alert works  

            var url = "http://api.alternativeto.net/software/firefox?callback=?";

            $.getJSON(url, function(data) <== this should be, but isn't being called
            {
                alert("function data called");  <== so this alert doesn't show.      

             } // end function (data) 

            ); // end getJSON

            alert("getJSON call completed");    <== and this alert works
        } //  end search click.function()
    ); // end $(
```

The "search clicked" and "getJSON call completed" alerts both work. The returned JSON I get from entering the url in a browser is valid.

The test code is from this URL:

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I don't believe you need the `?callback=?` in your `url` since you can make cross-domain requests from an app (I have had success with `$.getJSON('http://google.com/', function (data) {console.log(data);})`).

Comment: Thanks - that helped me to look at the log instead of alerts, where I saw that there's some kind of whitelist problem. I consider this solved, so if you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you need the `?callback=?` in your `url` since you can make cross-domain requests from an app.

I have had success with:

```
$.getJSON('http://google.com/', function (data) {console.log(data);});
```

..which logged the HTML of Google's homepage.

Comment: @JackBeNimble Yeah I remember testing it on iOS 4.3 and it worked. But now that I think about it I used `alert(data)` since I couldn't figure out how to make `console.log(data)` work (I'm pretty new to Xcode).

Comment: sorry - I had to change from accept to upvote - I've gotten rid of the  whitelist issue, but it's still not executing the callback.

Comment: No, it is working - it must have been a syntax error. Thanks!

Comment: Not working it's not doing anything and also not displaying any console logs

Comment: @ArpitGarg If you'd like help feel free to ask, most likely you've got something else setup incorrectly.

Comment: @Jasper m using same code as shown above : The setup seems to be fine as log"testing log" is showing . Also there is no error shown                    console.log("testing log");
$.getJSON('http://google.com/', function (data) {console.log(data);});